# cannot open report after save

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I've closed a report and answered 'yes' to the save action popup.
Since then, I can't open the report and receiving this error in my browser console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'consumedEntities' of null
    at ic3report-all.js?v=2018353111537:5711
    at l (base-libraries.min.js?v=2018353111537:151)
    at Function.An.reduce (base-libraries.min.js?v=2018353111537:264)
    at ReportLayout.consumedEntities (ic3report-all.js?v=2018353111537:5711)
    at ic3report-all.js?v=2018353111537:3702
    at r (base-libraries.min.js?v=2018353111537:150)
    at Function.Xe (base-libraries.min.js?v=2018353111537:212)
    at EntityArrayContainer.forEachEntry (ic3report-all.js?v=2018353111537:3379)
    at ic3report-all.js?v=2018353111537:3702
    at Function.MigrationUtils.migrateReport (ic3report-all.js?v=2018353111537:7985)
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit: version 6.8.5

Comment: which version of the reporting application and server are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

icCube 6.8.5: the layout definition might have been corrupted (saving non necessay null information); icCube 6.8.6 will be improved to ignore as much as possible error in the layout definition when opening a report.